# Jumping to corresponding / matching Brackets in Coda Editor

Tags: coda

I'm using Coda IDE on Mac OSX.
In eclipse there's a feature called "Jump to matching bracket" (invoked by Command+Shift+P).
Is there any equivalent, or perhaps a plugin, in Coda ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know this is months later, but figured better to leave my findings here in case someone else winds up here, too.

I recently started using Coda 2 and have been looking to just jump to a matching bracket (in Textpad on Windows it was something like Ctrl+M).

This is the closest I've found:

- For visualizing: while typing passing over a bracket will animate a circle over its matching one (you're out of luck if it's off thescreen!)
- For cursor placement: at the parenthesis or bracket <kbd>Command+B</kbd> (or double clicking it) will select the block, you can then just hit the left or right arrow to move past or preceding the selection
- For both: you can use cold folding, <kbd>Ctrl+Command+left arrow</kbd> to fold and right arrow to unfold
- For HTML: try this plugin and use <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd>: Zen.Coding-Coda.v0.7.1.zip ([Github](https://github.com/downloads/sergeche/zen-coding/Zen.Coding-Coda.v0.7.1.zip) | [Google Code](https://zen-coding.googlecode.com/files/Zen.Coding-Coda.v0.7.1.zip)) (don't use the new version named Emmet or something to that effect, the plugin did not work for me, this old one I'm linking to still seems to work for Coda 2 as of this writing (Coda 2.0.4))

Not as obvious as other editors/IDEs and may take some getting used to.